# Constructor is undefined

Tags: java, arraylist

package in.citydoor.imports.catalog.tools;

public class ProductVo {

```
private String product_id;
private String product_name;

public void ProductVo(String i, String n){

    product_id = i;
    product_name = n;

}


public String getProductId(){
  return this.product_id;
}

public void setProductId(String product_id){
    this.product_id = product_id;
}

public String getProductName(){
    return this.product_name;
}

public void setProductname(String product_name){
    this.product_name = product_name;
}
```

}

package in.citydoor.imports.catalog.tools;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CatFeedBean {

```
ArrayList<ProductVo> parsedList = new ArrayList<ProductVo>();
ArrayList<PriceVo> priceList = new ArrayList<PriceVo>();
ArrayList<SkuVo> SkuList = new ArrayList<SkuVo>();

String[] columns = arryLines.split("/");

//String[] columns;

String productid = columns[0];
String productname = columns[1];
String skuid = columns[2];
String price = columns[3];

**ProductVo productObj = new ProductVo(productid,productname);**

//parsedList.add(productObj);
//SkuVo skuObj =  new SkuVo(skuid);
//SkuList.add(skuObj);
//PriceVo priceObj = new PriceVo(price);
//priceList.add(priceObj);
```

}

At the Bold line, I am getting an error - "The Constructor ProductVo(String, String) is undefined".

Comment: `public void ProductVo` isn't declaring a constructor... it's declaring a `void` method called `ProductVo`. Remove the `void` part.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a constructor -- it's a method returning `void`.

```
public void ProductVo(String i, String n){
```

Remove the `void` to make it a constructor.  You named it the same as your class, which is good, but constructors have no return type declared, not even `void`.

```
public ProductVo(String i, String n){
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a constructor:

```
public void ProductVo(String i, String n){  
    product_id = i;
    product_name = n;    
}
```

but this is (note the absence of the return type - in this case `void`):

```
public ProductVo(String i, String n){   
    product_id = i;
    product_name = n;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the return type `void` in defining the constructor, as a constructor has no return type.